# Permissions-Policy autoplay

Tags: html, http, browser, specifications, policy

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Permissions-Policy/autoplay) mention that we can allow autoplay for videos by setting `Permissions-Policy` header for the document. I tried testing this, but it's still raising the the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`.

Here's how I tested it.

This is the http server.

```py
from http import server

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()

        server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def send_my_headers(self):
        # Setting header
        self.send_header("Permissions-Policy", 'autoplay=("https://sample-videos.com")')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.test(HandlerClass=MyHTTPRequestHandler)
```

And this is the document that autoplays a video (with audio)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Autoplay testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
<script defer>
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.classList.add('playing')
    video.src = 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4'
    video.playsInline = true
    video.autoplay = true
    video.load()
    document.body.appendChild(video)
    video.play()
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser and which version of it are you using?

Comment: Tested on chrome 114

Answer (score 0):

The `Permissions-Policy` header affcts only `<iframe>` elements, so it won't work in your case. Alternatively, if you don't need audio, you can add the `muted` attribute to your `<video>` element. It will disable video's audio, but also the `autoplay` block.

```
<video src="./path/to/video.mp4" autoplay muted>
```

Comment: From the docs: The HTTP Permissions-Policy header provides a mechanism to allow and deny the use of browser features in a document or within any <iframe> elements in the document.